# Desplegar botones con jQuery

Tags: html, jquery, materialize, mouse

Necesito agregar un efecto a un botón en mi html, que al posicionar el cursor se desplieguen otros dos botones hacia arriba con su animación y cuando retire el cursor, se vuelvan a esconder.

Sé que con las funciones de jQuery mouseenter() y mouseleave() se puede lograr. También se puede lograr con Materialize (ejemplo abajo). ¿Cuáles son los scripts necesarios para que funcione? (Abajo dejo la librería)

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.7/css/materialize.min.css">

<div class="fixed-action-btn" style="bottom: 45px; right: 24px;">
  <a class="btn-floating btn-large red">
    <i class="large material-icons">mode_edit</i>
  </a>
  <ul>
    <li><a class="btn-floating red"><i class="material-icons">insert_chart</i></a></li>
    <li><a class="btn-floating yellow darken-1"><i class="material-icons">format_quote</i></a></li>
    <li><a class="btn-floating green"><i class="material-icons">publish</i></a></li>
    <li><a class="btn-floating blue"><i class="material-icons">attach_file</i></a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.7/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Por lo que veo ya funciona, no entiendo a qué te refieres cuando dices cuales son los scripts necesarios, te refieres al código para que funcione mediante jQuery?

Comment: Efectivamente @Ivan-San, los únicos scripts de la librería que hace que funcione..

Comment: @Ivan-San tiene razon, Si pruebas tu **Snippet** veras que esta funcionado

Comment: @FRANCISCOJ.BLANCO, no voy a copiar toda la librería de materialize para hacer funcionar sólo un botón... ¿tú la copiarías toda?

Comment: @Candelo, entonces edita tu pregunta ya que no esta formulada como es, estas preguntando que necesitas `agregar un efecto a un botón en mi html`  y tu ejemplo lo contesta

Comment: @FRANCISCOJ.BLANCO, si lees atentamente el final de la pregunta, verás que dice: **¿Cuáles son los scripts NECESARIOS para que funcione?**..

Comment: Esta bien pero podrías aclarar un poco, **agregar efecto a boton en HTML con css de Materialize** o también podría ser **Crear efecto de en botón al posicionar cursor**. Si por lo que entendí es realizar esto mismo que hace materialize con jQuery te puedo dejar un ejemplo.

Comment: Sí Iván, esto mismo pero con jQuery por favor, te agradezco inmensamente

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para poder tener una animación muy parecida a lo que materialize hace como bien dices podemos utilizar los eventos de **jQuery** `mouseenter` y el de `mouseleave`. 
Voy a remover la parte de materialize que contiene javascript y voy a recrear los  eventos.

---

Básicamente lo que hacemos es agregar la propiedad de `css` `transform` a los enlaces dentro del menú, para que se sobrepongan arriba. 
 Después cuando el evento de `mouseleave` se accione haremos lo inverso y pondremos `opacity` en `0` para ocultarlos.

```js
$('.btn-floating').on('mouseenter', function() {
  $(this).parent().addClass('active');
  $(this).next().children('li').children('a').animate({ 
 'transform': 'scaleY(1) scaleX(1) translateY(0px) translateX(0px)',
 'opacity': '1'
 });
});

$('.fixed-action-btn').on('mouseleave', function() {
 $(this).children('ul').children('li').children('a').animate({ 
 'transform': 'scaleY(0) scaleX(0) translateY(40px) translateX(40px)',
 'opacity': '0'
 });
 $(this).parent().removeClass('active');
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.7/css/materialize.min.css">

<div class="fixed-action-btn" style="bottom: 45px; right: 24px;">
  <a class="btn-floating btn-large red">
    <i class="large material-icons">mode_edit</i>
  </a>
  <ul>
    <li><a class="btn-floating red"><i class="material-icons">insert_chart</i></a></li>
    <li><a class="btn-floating yellow darken-1"><i class="material-icons">format_quote</i></a></li>
    <li><a class="btn-floating green"><i class="material-icons">publish</i></a></li>
    <li><a class="btn-floating blue"><i class="material-icons">attach_file</i></a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Mil gracias @Ivan-San, de por casualidad, ¿sabes cómo hacer que aparezcan en orden hacia arriba, así como el que yo puse?

Comment: Si, podrías ordenar el arreglo antes de agregarle la animación, o simplemente cambiando el código fuente a cómo tú desees

Comment: Iván, me refiero a el efecto de aparecer los botones uno tras el otro, como en el snippet que adjunté.. Mil gracias.